# Change order of text on single line on a whole file using bash tools

Tags: string, bash, awk, grep, kml

I have a simple, long KML file like this:

```
<Placemark>  <name>name</name><description><![CDATA[text]]></description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>53.1074160507479,-1.59813015453956,0</coordinates>  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Unfortunately, the coordinates are in the wrong order. It should read:

```
<Placemark>  <name>name</name><description><![CDATA[text]]></description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-1.59813015453956,53.1074160507479,0</coordinates>  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Using bash tools, awk or similar (sed, grep etc), how can I convert the coordinates in the whole text file to the right format?

What I've tried:

I know that that I can select the first set of numbers using

```
 grep -o -P '(?<=inates\>).*(?=,-)'
```

and I know I could easily create a similar command to get the second co-ordinate.

I'm lost on how to substitute them in place or write them out. What'd be a good way to do it?

Newbie here. Relatively low level of technical knowledge. I'd prefer easy to understand in linux CLI tools if possible.

Comment: `grep` is used to extract lines/matches. You need `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

a hacky script

```
$ awk '/\<coordinates\>/{split($0,line,"[>,]"); 
                         sub(line[3],line[2]); 
                         sub(line[2],line[3])}1' file

<Placemark>  <name>name</name><description><![CDATA[text]]></description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-1.59813015453956,53.1074160507479,0</coordinates>  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

find the line, split based on the delimiters, swap the elements and print all lines.  To eliminate false positive matches, perhaps anchor the replacements with the delimiters.

```
$ awk -v c=',' '/\<coordinates\>/{split($0,line,"[>,]"); 
                                  sub(c line[3] c,c line[2] c);
                                  sub(">"line[2] c,">"line[3] c)}1' file

<Placemark>  <name>name</name><description><![CDATA[text]]></description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-1.59813015453956,53.1074160507479,0</coordinates>  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score -2):

My friend told me to [paste this into my text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgWr0.jpg) and it worked!

Comment: That's not an answer to the question you asked though (`Using bash tools, awk or similar (sed, grep etc), how can I ...?`) so you shouldn't have it posted as an answer here.